# Point configuration given distribution of distances

Tags: distributions, multiple-comparisons, distance, point-estimation

Does anybody know if there is a method/algorithm to find coordinates for $N$ points, given a probability density function from which the $N(N-1)/2$ different pairwise distances between them can be randomly sampled?

Note that techniques such as multidimensional scaling do not apply here, since I don't have a matrix of pairwise distances between the $N$ points.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you give an example of such a probability density function?

Comment: Well... I guess it can be any density function but, for instance, suppose we have 1000 points in the 2D plane. In R this would be x <- cbind(runif(n = 1000), runif(n = 1000)). Then we can approximate a density function from the pairwise distances between them: D <- as.matrix(dist(x)), df <- approxfun(density(D[upper.tri(D)])). Variable df is then the function that tells me with what probability I can sample distances from the density function. My problem is that I only know df and from there I would like to find valid coordinates for N points.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But I do have a preliminary observation. Suppose the underlying density for observations is standard normal. (I've simplified this to a 1-dimensional problem.) One can compute the density for the distance from an arbitrary point x0, and then one can integrate the arbitrary point out using the original standard normal. The result is a half-normal distribution corresponding to a normal with a 2.

Comment: I'm new to this, and apparently I took to long to finish my comment. So here goes again. "... corresponding to a normal with a _variance_ of 2." Are there other distributions on the real line that produce this distribution for the density of distances? I don't know. Regarding your question, how can one use the half-normal to construct a distribution on the real line that satisfies the distance density? I don't know that either.